# Why OpenCV Manager and neon needed in android?

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

can anyone give me idea for why we need opencv manager to run sample application of openCV library in android..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/android/service/doc/Intro.html

OpenCV Manager is just the library itself but packed in an app and updated by the OpenCV team, you have OpenCV always up-to-date for your applications.

Neon is a set of instructions for ARM SoC that can make the execution of the code that uses NEON instructions faster.

As always you can also build and link OpenCV on your own; there is no need to do that, it's just convenient in the typical scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply.can you please tell me how to build and link openCV. so that i won't be asked with any packages to be installed when i run my application of face detection.

Comment: just use the NDK, internet is full of tutorial about this, also there is something about this on the official docs  http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html

Comment: i forgot to write that: Neon is not available on all the ARM devices, it's an ARM set but it depends on what the SoC maker provides to you.

Comment: when I am  trying to Build application with C++ native part from Eclipse it shows Error: Program "/ndk-build" not found in PATH
PATH=[/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games]  I am using ubuntu..So what path should i give here??

Comment: I have also Defined the NDKROOT environment variable containing the path to Android NDK in my system.

Comment: just Google for this kind of problems, most of the time they are just about using the right steps and setup, anyway there is an official NDK plugin for Eclipse that you can download from the same repository that you use for the SDK plugin for Eclipse, once installed you can use it like that http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin , also remember to add C/C++ support to Eclipse by installing the CDT plugin from the Eclipse repository.

Comment: ya I have installed NDK and CDT plugins to my eclipse.

Comment: ya i did read your link..but still no change I have already followed all the steps specified..

Comment: I have figured out the solution for Error: Program "/ndk-build" not found in PATH PATH=[/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games] error..The solution is that We have to set ndk path to the environment file also in ubuntu which is in etc/environment..edit it using as root user.